# SQL ReportServer - HTTP request is not allowed for client authentication scheme "Ntlm"

Tags: c#, ntlm-authentication, reportserver

So, I have a problem with C# .net 8  and ReportServer 14.0.600.594. When I'm setting parameter I get a message error 'HTTP request is not allowed for client authentication scheme "Ntlm" '

I use C# .NET8.0 and ReportViewerCore.NETCore 15.1.1

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore;
using System.Net;


ServerReport report = new ServerReport();

report.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("f.toto", "abs12e44+-", "mydomain.local");
report.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("https://prodreportserver.myserver.cpù/reportserver");
report.ReportPath = "/MyReports_RH/Test";
report.SetParameters(new[] { new ReportParameter("dReference", "01/01/23") });
report.SetParameters(new[] { new ReportParameter("GuidGeneric", "77f23cb4-42f2-461a-8b92-b544c8782b40") });


byte[] pdf = report.Render("PDF");
string filename = String.Concat("c:\\tmp\\", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".pdf");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, pdf);
```

when I set the first parameter I have this error 'HTTP request is not allowed for client authentication scheme "Ntlm" '

Into my rsreportserver.config I have :

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>    
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Allow</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Any</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>True</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

I try to change authentication types or use ImpersonationUser

```
report.ReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

but I have the same message. Why?

Thank for your help.